# Setting the line and height of a line using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS.
I have developed a page.I want to do the designing like this.

[image]

<sup>(Right click open in new tab)</sup>

I have done the header line with the help of CSS.Coding i have done.

```
<div id="fourth_page_table1">
    Address Type &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&  nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Residing From      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;City &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;State Code &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Country Code&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Phone Number &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cell Number
</div>

<div id="fourth_page_table1_leftlin1">
|
</div>
```

**css**

```
         #fourth_page_table1
           {
           width:900px;
           left:230px;
           top:240px;
           position:absolute;
           font-size:16px;
           background-color:#33CCFF;
           }
        #fourth_page_table1_leftlin1
          {
           left:230px;
           top:240px;
           position:absolute;
           font-size:70px;
           height:20px;
           width:10px;
           line-height:100%;
         }
```

After doing this coding the output is not coming properly.

```
     Please check my output.      
         [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDmTF.jpg
```

The left line i want to set from the left and in thin format.
How to make a long line vertically ,that i am not able to do ?
I have tried with line-height but i am not getting the proper output according to my above figure.
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: where is a javascript here? Do not add irrelevant tags.

Comment: what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Please check my output figure the left line i want to set like the first figure .How to make the line thinner and longer ? That i am not getting ?

Comment: @Cool: This is not the right way mate, abandon it and use the way suggested in pctr's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating tables, you should be using the [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) element.

Once you have your table, you can then add border with css like this:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Of course, you can specify your own width, line style and color of the border.

Also, please avoid adding padding through `&nbsp;` characters. This makes your markup difficult to read and is in general a bad practice. Use css `padding` and `margin` rules instead.